# Apache If Else documentroot

Tags: apache-2.4, documentroot

I want to change the **Apache DocumentRoot setting** depending on what IP address is accessing the server. I have added this code to the vhost.conf file but Apache always accepts the last declaration of mydocumentroot and ignores the if statement logic.

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == 91.123.232.226">
    Define mydocumentroot /var/www/main-site/
</If>
<Else>
     Define mydocumentroot /var/www/holding-page/
</Else>

 DocumentRoot ${mydocumentroot}
```

Comment: Just because I'm curious, could you try `<If "-R '91.123.232.226/32'">` please?

Comment: if this is correct answer, please answer it as answer so it can be accepted and read by others as correct answer